# __userpurge call (IDA)

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to call a function from another dll, know her exact address and parameters.

In IDA:

```
int __userpurge  sub_104CC1A0<eax>(int a1<ecx>, double a2<st0>, int a3)
```

I found a similar answer on stackoverflow.com, but I get the error:

```
struct typechat
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int type; 
};

typechat * point;   
DWORD callAddress = 0x4CC1A0 + baseaddr;

    __declspec(naked) int SendMsg(char * text, double time, typechat * a3)
    {
            __asm{
                push ebp
                mov ebp, esp
                push ebx
                push a3
                mov st0, time // error C2415: invalid operand type
                mov ecx, text
                call[callAddress]
                pop ebx
                leave
                ret
        }
    }
```

**error C2415: invalid operand type**

```
switch ( *(_DWORD *)(a3 + 8) )//chat type ,[code from IDA]
{


}
```

UPDATE:

```
_
//int __userpurge  sub_104CC1A0<eax>(int a1<ecx>, double a2<st0>, int a3)

declspec(naked) int SendMsg(char * text, double nTime, typechat * nType)
{
    __asm{
            push ebp
            mov ebp, esp
            push nType
            fld nTime
            push ecx
            mov ecx, text
            move eax, [callAddress]
                call eax
            pop ecx
            leave
            ret
    }

}
```

This function too does not work! : (Not called callAddress)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot `MOV` a value into the `ST0` register, you must use `FLD` instead, eg:

```
fld time
```